# ¿Cómo puedo centrar un botón dentro de un Frame con tkinter en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Pues bueno, estoy tratando de ponerle un botón a un Frame llamado "SlideMenu", y cuando trato de cambiarle la posición moviendolo al centro, no puedo hacerlo, se queda en la esquina el botón. Tampoco sé como cambiarle el tamaño al botón, y es un problema porque no queda bien. El botón es "self.WatchNewsBtn":

```
from tkinter import *
from  tkinter.ttk import Separator


class program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initializecomponents()
        pass

    def initializecomponents(self):
        min_width, min_height = 870, 700
        self.Form = Tk()
        self.SlideMenu = Frame(self.Form)
        self.WatchNewsBtn = Button(self.SlideMenu, background="white", padx=5, pady=5)


        # SlideMenu
        self.SlideMenu.pack(side="left", anchor="c", fill="y")
        self.SlideMenu.config(background="#404040", width=300, height=min_height)
        self.SlideMenu.grid_propagate(False)

        # WatchNewsBtn
        self.WatchNewsBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.WatchNewsBtn.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.WatchNewsBtn.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # MainForm
        self.Form.title = "News"
        self.Form.resizable(True, True)
        self.Form.state("zoomed")
        self.Form.minsize(min_width, min_height)
        self.Form.config(background="#646464")
        self.Form.mainloop()
        pass
    pass
#start
program()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiarle el tamaño al botón solo tienes que añadir `width` y `height` y ya lo ajustas como quieras.

```
self.WatchNewsBtn = Button(self.SlideMenu, background="white", padx=5, pady=5, width=15, height=5)
```

Para que aparezca en el centro, el problema está en `self.SlideMenu.grid_propagate(0)` sin embargo si lo quitas, el tamaño se ajusta al tamaño del botón más grande que pongas en el Frame (aunque se coloquen en el centro dichos botones).

Una opción que puedes utilizar es que no utilices `pack()` en el Frame, sino que lo posiciones con `grid()` a la izquierda, aunque en este caso, la longitud deberías ponerla de forma manual, no funcionaría `fill='y'`